# Is there such thing as dataset improvement?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I know that we can use explained machine learning to find why a model chose a certain classification.

I wonder if there is a way I can find which features are going to improve my current model.

I will explain what I mean by this.

Case: NLP classification of sports, there is a paragraph talking about Ronaldo scores against Uruguay...

Is there a method that can ask which Ronaldo you mean (Ronaldo de Lime the Brazilian player or Cristiano Ronaldo the Portuguese)?

so the model can get a higher accuracy result to classify the paragraph about Brazilian Team or about Portugal Team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could use some named entity recognition (NER) mechanism to detect "Ronaldo" as a person's name. then you could ask users about him and finally narrow down final answers based on the user's input.